# autoptimize + cache enabler: randomly single pages don't load stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, caching, optimization, plugins

To improve page speed and user experience, I've tested many plugins dedicated for this.
So based on real results and many online testing (gtmetrix, google pagespeed, webpagetest) I moved to Autoptimize + Cache Enabler plugin solution.

1) What happens

I don't know why but randomly, only on some pages or only one, the content is loaded but completely without any css stylesheet, so the page comes out quite empty and all is messed up.
Last time it happened, I've examined the page with chrome dev tools and I've noticed which the all autoptimize's stylesheets weren't there: like the site doesn't have any of my css.

Clearing first the cache of "Cache enabler" then the cache of "Autoptimize" everything turned nice again.

2) The problem

I think this happened after wordpress auto-uptades, but I'm not sure.
Anyway, the real problem is that if it happens randomly and not only with WP updates, I can't control the situation and know when purge the cache and when not.
So I could have "blank" pages for weeks and don't know anything about it: bounce +1000% :)

I've already set time duration of cache from  "Cache Enabler" setting on 48h, so it should refresh automatically. Is it the right time to set?
I cannot make the same for "Autoptimize" plugin because it does not provide this option of auto-purge.

Before I change everything and move to other plugins and many other tests, does anybody know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Maybe disabling some optimizing setting on both plugins?

P.S.
Unfortunately I can't provide you with the error page because it happens randomly and I can't generate the error by myself.

Autoptimize + cache enabler problems (maybe plugin configuration settings?)

Comment: I think that the problem start from “cache enabler” plugin, because when i clear its cache everything turn fine. At the Moment the only change i’ve made is caching expire time from 72h to 6h.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use `W3 total cache plugin` instead of `Cache Enabler plugin`. It is working fine for me. I have use Autoptimize with w3 total cache plugin on multiple sites. No CSS and JQuery conflict by using this.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/
```

Comment: Thanks nilesh for your comment. Anyway I’ve started with that and for a while everything worked fine, then suddently the whole website became very slow. My hosting provider explain me which was a common problem of that plugin (probably this mid-low cost hosting cant support that).

Comment: After I moved on WP Fastest Cache and at least I moved on Autoptimize+Cache enabler (best performance than everyone I’ve tryed before)